# add button over tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Is it possible to add a button over a tabbar controller using interface builder?

I am trying to do this in interface builder but every time I add the button over tabbar it fills up the rest of the screen with the button instead of just putting the button over the tabbar.

Something like the camera in instagram.

Comment: No, in interface builder, it is not possible. Because interface builder takes that button as view & tries to replace the controller's view with button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i solved the problem:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cameraTabBarItem.png"];
    UIImage *highlightImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cameraTabBarItem.png"];
    UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:highlightImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    CGFloat heightDifference = buttonImage.size.height - self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
    if (heightDifference < 0)
        button.center = self.tabBarController.tabBar.center;
    else
    {
        CGPoint center = self.tabBarController.tabBar.center;
        center.y = center.y - heightDifference/2.0;
        button.center = center;
    }
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(share:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:button];
}
```

Comment: I tried adding a UIButton to a tabbar view as you did but I experience a lot of issues when I push view controllers is navigation bars that are embedded in my tabbar. Have you experienced similar issues? Did you manage to solve them? thanks

Comment: hey have u found the solution for push?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add your button as a subview of your App Delegate's window:

```
[self.window addSubview:myButton];
```